# Показать select при выборе значения с другого select

Tags: javascript, css, html-select

Здравствуйте, есть такой простой пример, при выборе значения первого `select` появляется второй при помощи изменения параметра `css`. Все хорошо работает, но не могу понять как сделать третий шаг, чтоб при выборе значения второго `select` появлялся третий, либо при выборе в первом появлялось два - второй и третий.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#select1").change(function () {
    var x = $('select option:selected').attr('name');
    $('#step2').find('select').css('display','none');
    $('#'+x).css('display','block');
})
});
</script>
<style>
 #step2 select{
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<select id="select1">
<option selected disabled>Выбирите</option>
<option name="select1_step2">А</option>
<option name="select2_step2">a</option>
</select>

<div id="step2">
<select id="select1_step2">
<option selected disabled>Выбирите</option>
<option>А</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
</select>
<select id="select2_step2">
<option selected disabled>Выбирите</option>
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
<option>d</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Буду очень благодарна за помощь

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#select1').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  //если элемент с id равным значению #select1 существует
  if($('#' + val).length){
     //скрываем все селекты шага 2
    $('#step2 select').hide();
    //показываем нужный
    $('#' + val).show();
    //в противном случае, если значение равняется "all"
  }else if(val == 'all'){
    //показать все списки шага2
    $('#step2 select').show();
  }
})
```

```css
#step2 select{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
<option selected disabled>Выбирите</option>
<option value="select2_1">Список1</option>
<option value="select2_2">Список2</option>
<option value="all">Оба списка</option>
</select>

<div id="step2">
  <select id="select2_1">
<option selected disabled>Выбирите(список1)</option>
<option>А</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
</select>
  <select id="select2_2">
<option selected disabled>Выбирите(список2)</option>
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
<option>d</option>
</select>
</div>
```